# ov5642 not working in 30fps

Tags: linux, camera, gstreamer, frame-rate

We have a customized i.MX6Q Board based on sabrelite reference board.

We have the following configuration:

Linux : 3.10.53

Gstreamer 1.0 latest i.MX6 Plugins

We connected OV5642 Camera over CSI Interface..Used the following command to display the camera output on the screen.

```
gst-launch-1.0 imxv4l2videosrc device=/dev/video0 imx-capture-mode=4 fps-n=15 ! imxipuvideosink
```

It works, but initially, it takes time to settle for few seconds,  there is genlock issue

But when I modify the fps to 30, I get distorted output.. What do you think is wrong here.. Any help is appreciated...

[image]

Comment: Could be related to imxv4l2videosrc. Obviously you also guessed it since you also posted the same question on [GitHub](https://github.com/Freescale/gstreamer-imx/issues/203).  Setting the environment variable `GST_DEBUG=3` could give you more information. `3` means `FIXME`, so you would see if this is a problem some developer is already aware of. See [Running GStreamer Applications](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gst-running.html) for more information on `GST_DEBUG`

Comment: May be u r right.. I will look into it.. Copy the above as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be related to imxv4l2videosrc. Obviously you also guessed it since you also posted the same question on [GitHub](https://github.com/Freescale/gstreamer-imx/issues/203). Setting the environment variable `GST_DEBUG=3` could give you more information. `3` means `FIXME`, so you would see if this is a problem some developer is already aware of. See [Running GStreamer Applications](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gst-running.html) for more information on `GST_DEBUG`.